# loading huge (8GB) binary file and shifting it in memory C++ Linux 64bit

Tags: c++, linux, 64-bit

I am trying to read 8GB binary file into memory and manipulate it.
File contains sequence HEADER, DATA, HEADER, DATA, .... and I would like to shift it (in memory) to: DATA, DATA, DATA, ...

It is greyscale 16bit image data.

My problem is that I can only use sequential uproach (code following) because .read() function only works with 32 bit register and also pointers bellow only allow me to have 32bit max number of unsigned shorts.

Is there something I am missing? It is on 64bit linux with 64GB RAM so this is plenty. (and it really needs to be all at once in memory)
Can I get somehow more pointers then [2^32]? I could then read it sequentially into them if read is my only option I guess.

EDIT: I updated my code, it does not complain about anything, only the memove gives me segmentation fault (for j>=448). Any ideas why?

Example code:

```
const unsigned int HEADERSIZE=384;
ifstream fs;
fs.open("./myfile.bin", ios::in | ios::binary);

unsigned short *tmp0 = new unsigned short [256*256*256*256+HEADERSIZE/2*256*256];
unsigned short *tmpNoHead = new unsigned short [256*256*256*256];

fs.read((char*)tmp0, 2*256*256*256*256+HEADERSIZE*256*256);
//endian swap
unsigned char*c0 = (unsigned char*)tmp0;
for (long i = 0; i < HEADERSIZE*256*256+256*256*256*256*2; i += 2)
swap(c0[i], c0[i + 1]);

//memmove or memcpy seg fault if j>=448
for (int j = 0; j<256*256;j++) memmove(tmpNoHead+j*256*256,c0+HEADERSIZE*(j+1)+j*256*256*2,256*256*2);

fs.close();
return 0;
```

Comment: On 64-bit linux `int` should be 64 bits.

Answer (score 0):

On 64-bit systems, although a short is 16-bits and an int is still 32-bits, *pointers* are 64-bits, so you can indeed access your whole 8GB data array with short* or int* pointers.

To prove this to yourself, you can run this:

```
printf("sizeof(short*) = %lu\n", sizeof(short*));
```

On my 64-bit machine, 8 (64-bits) is printed.

Be careful with your i+j*DATA_SIZE line, if the sum can exceed 2^31 you should make i and j long ints.

Comment: funny enough, multiplication within the read() and new types was probably the cause of seg fault